# How to get rid of parent hover when hover to child div?

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div class="div_a">
    <div>text</div>
    <div class="div_close"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div_a {pointer:cursor; z-index:100;}
.div_a:hover {border:1px solid red;}
.div_close {pointer:cursor; z-index:9999;}
.div_close:hover {border:1px solid blue;}
```

When I hover to `.div_a`, then `div` gets red border.

And when I hover to `.div_close`, then `.div_a` has red border and `.div_close` has blue border.

I want when I hover to `.div_close`, just `.div_close` has blue border.

*How can I remove `.div_a`'s border when I hover to `.div_close`?*

Answer (score 2):

Why not move the hover to the text element?

```css
.div_a {pointer:cursor; z-index:100;}
.div_a:hover {border:1px solid red;}
.div_close {pointer:cursor; z-index:9999;}
.div_close:hover {border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="div_a">text</div>
    <div class="div_close">close</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look to this snippet i have solved it exactly what you want i guess

```js
function addClass(o, c){  
  document.getElementById("div_a").className = "withoutBorder";
    var re = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + c + "(\\s|$)", "g")
    if (re.test(o.className)) return
    o.className = (o.className + " " + c).replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/(^ | $)/g, "")
}
 
function removeClass(o, c){
document.getElementById("div_a").className = "withBorder";
    var re = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + c + "(\\s|$)", "g")
    o.className = o.className.replace(re, "$1").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/(^ | $)/g, "")
}
```

```css
.div_a {pointer:cursor; z-index:100;}
.div_a:hover {border:1px solid red;}
.div_close {pointer:cursor; z-index:9999;}
.div_close:hover {border:1px solid blue;}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.active {
 border:1px solid red;
 
}
.hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.withBorder{
border:1px solid red;
}
.withoutBorder{
border:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_a">
    <div>text</div>
    <div id="div_close"
    onmouseout="removeClass(this, 'active');" onmouseover="addClass(this, 'active');">hello</div>
</div>
```